# How to get all of the process::Command output

Tags: rust, ssh, command, scp, rust-cargo

So I am trying to reconstruct a bash script I made using rust (allows for hashing and for more customization). I cannot seem to get the output of the command to my terminal though and I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have tried piping stdout in so many different ways already and I'm at a stand still.

I would like to see this part in the command line as well but just have it all being auto filled (and yes I know ssh keys exist lol)

```
user@server's password:
ibits.c                                                                  100% 1137   271.2KB/s   00:00
```

```
fn auto_scp(flags: FlagOptions, f_path: String) {
    let info = open_config();
    let mut args: Vec<String> = vec![];
    if flags.is_folder {
        args.push(String::from("-r"))
    }
    if flags.d_load {
        let path = info.rmt_hst+":"+&f_path;
        // println!("{}",path);
        args.push(path);
        args.push(info.ddest);
    } else {
        let path = info.rmt_hst+":"+&info.udest;
        // println!("{}",path);
        args.push(f_path);
        args.push(path);
    }
    let mut com = process::Command::new("/bin/scp")
                                  .args(args)
                                  .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
                                  .output()
                                  .expect("stuff");
    // io::stdout().write_all(b"hello world\n");
                                  // .expect("Could not output");
    // let stdout = String::from_utf8(com.stdout).unwrap();
    println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8(&com.stdout));
    // io::stdout().write_all(&outc.stdout).unwrap();
    println!("{}", stdout);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? Have you tried it without `.stdout(process::Stdio::piped())`? What you tried checking the stderr output?

Comment: @PitaJ I have tried both yes, I get nothing in both cases

Comment: Remove the `.stdout(process::Stdio::piped())` and replace `.output()` with `.status()`.

Comment: That just gives me the exit code which is not what I want, I want the stdout of the command to be visible by the user

Comment: For the stdout to be visible to the user, the easiest is _not_ to capture it yourself but simply let it through, which is what happens if you don't call `.stdout` nor `.output` but simply `.status` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=118aec5a3797cdc62cae6d6b032ee341)).

Comment: @Jmb I see, that does do what I want, my bad. Thanks a bunch. Is there a way I could pass the password through while requested as well? Would it be with .stdin(Stdio::piped()) ?

Comment: @Jmb also feel free to write it as an actual answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the stdout to be visible to the user, the easiest is not to capture it yourself but simply let it through, which is what happens if you don't call `.stdout` nor `.output` but simply `.status` or `.spawn`:

```
fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new ("/usr/bin/echo")
        .arg ("Hello world")
        .status()
        .unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=118aec5a3797cdc62cae6d6b032ee341)

If you want to pass input to the child process (e.g. a password), you need to call `.stdin (Stdio::piped())` before spawning the child (with `.spawn`), which will give you a [`Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) handle whose `stdin` field can be used to write to the child:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::process::{ Command, Stdio, };

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new ("/usr/bin/cat")
        .stdin (Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let mut pipe = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
    pipe.write_all ("hello world".as_bytes()).unwrap();
    drop (pipe); // So that `cat` will exit
    child.wait().unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=38f0c1db59d25fcc4bb7efb83672cfa7)

Comment: So it comes up asking for the password, but the pipe won't write to the password position? It is waiting for input, that might have something to do with it? Or its like passing before it asks

Comment: I'm not sure what you call the password "position". There is no notion of "position" in processes stdin/stdout. If the password isn't taken, do you send a `\n` after the password (to simulate the `<return>` key)? Otherwise you may need to ask a new question, and show us the code you use to send the password.